A formula for lexicographical ordering/ranking of n-tuples when elements of the tuples are repeated.
I have the following $n$ sets  $\{1,2,\cdots,j_1\}$;$\{1,2,\cdots,j_2\}$; $\cdots$; $\{1,2,\cdots,j_n\}$. I select exactly one element from each set and form $m=\prod_{k=1}^n j_k$ $n$-tuples. What is the formula for the lexicographical order? Example: Let $n=3$, $j_1=2$, $j_2=3$, $j_3=1$. So I want to map $(1,1,1)$ to $1$, $(1,2,1)$ to $2$, $(1,3,1)$ to $3$, $(2,1,1)$ to $4$, $(2,2,1)$ to $5$, $(2,3,1)$ to $6$.

For an $n-$tuple given by $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$, the lexicographical position can be calculated by,
\begin{equation}
   p  = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ (x_k - 1) \prod_{k'=1}^{k-1} j_{k'}\right]
\end{equation}
You can get the $n-$tuple back from position by,
\begin{equation}
   x_k = 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{p - 1}{\prod_{k'=1}^{k-1} j_{k'}} \right\rfloor \mod j_k
\end{equation}
